# Return result as Map from JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I was wondering if there is easy way to generate Map for the results from the query using JdbcTemplate. I have a query which returns two columns so I want to make map from the result directly.

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE somecol='someval';
```

Expected map:

```
{123,ABC},{456,DEF} .... {890, XYZ}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to return a map of column-name: column-value pairs using JdbcTemplate, but what you have described in your question is not an actual map.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getList() {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");
}
```

Would return:

```
[{'id': 123, 'name': 'ABC'}, {...}, ... ]
```

See the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) instead of JDBCTemplate. And use method [queryForMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource%29).
And your param put like this:

```
SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("somecol",someval);
```